# Server error while running a web project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, birt

Here i come with some error in console while running a web project First of all i am very  new to web project so i download a  web project in "Web" but while running it showing some error like this .i dono what happening ..could some one point out this error provide solution

In Console:

```
Apr 11, 2014 3:19:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        INFO: Servlet loadReport is currently unavailable
        Apr 11, 2014 3:19:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        INFO: Servlet loadReport is currently unavailable
        Apr 11, 2014 3:19:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        INFO: Marking servlet getPageCount as unavailable
        Apr 11, 2014 3:19:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
        SEVERE: Error loading WebappClassLoader
          context: /BirtIntegration
          delegate: false
          repositories:
            /WEB-INF/classes/
        ----------> Parent Classloader:
        org.apache.catalina.loader.StandardClassLoader@18fe8fc
         BirtIntegration.Controller.BirtReportPaginaitonController
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BirtIntegration.Controller.BirtReportPaginaitonController
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

        Apr 11, 2014 3:19:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet getPageCount
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: BirtIntegration.Controller.BirtReportPaginaitonController
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1128)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:129)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

        Apr 11, 2014 3:20:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        INFO: Servlet loadReport is currently unavailable
        Apr 11, 2014 3:20:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
        INFO: Servlet getPageCount is currently unavailable
```

Update another Error::

```
org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened while running the report.
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.EngineTask.handleFatalExceptions(EngineTask.java:2360)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.run(RunTask.java:86)
    at BirtIntegration.BirtViewer.ReportRenderer.processReportDesignDocAndRenderReport(ReportRenderer.java:109)
    at BirtIntegration.BirtViewer.ReportProcessor.processReport(ReportProcessor.java:60)
    at BirtIntegration.Controller.BirtReportController.doGet(BirtReportController.java:31)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
    at java.net.URI.toURL(URI.java:1095)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.ResourceLocatorUtil.getInputStream(ResourceLocatorUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.XMLSourceFromPath.openInputStream(XMLSourceFromPath.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.SaxParser.<init>(SaxParser.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.util.SaxParserConsumer.<init>(SaxParserConsumer.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.oda.xml.impl.ResultSet.next(ResultSet.java:142)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.oda.consumer.helper.OdaResultSet.next(OdaResultSet.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.ResultSet.fetch(ResultSet.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.dscache.DataSetToCache.fetchFromDataSet(DataSetToCache.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.dscache.DataSetToCache.fetch(DataSetToCache.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.OdiAdapter.fetch(OdiAdapter.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.fetch(RowResultSet.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.doNext(RowResultSet.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.RowResultSet.next(RowResultSet.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.ExpandableRowResultSet.next(ExpandableRowResultSet.java:63)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.populateData(SmartCacheHelper.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.initInstance(SmartCacheHelper.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCacheHelper.getResultSetCache(SmartCacheHelper.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.cache.SmartCache.<init>(SmartCache.java:74)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassUtil.populateOdiResultSet(PassUtil.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassUtil.pass(PassUtil.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.doSinglePass(PassManager.java:170)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.prepareDataSetResultSet(PassManager.java:94)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.pass.PassManager.populateDataSetResultSet(PassManager.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.ResultSetPopulator.cacheDataSet(ResultSetPopulator.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.transform.CachedResultSet.<init>(CachedResultSet.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.executor.DataSourceQuery.execute(DataSourceQuery.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery$OdaDSQueryExecutor.executeOdiQuery(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:466)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryExecutor.execute(QueryExecutor.java:1208)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.ServiceForQueryResults.executeQuery(ServiceForQueryResults.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.QueryResults.getResultIterator(QueryResults.java:178)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.QueryResultSet.<init>(QueryResultSet.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doExecuteQuery(DteDataEngine.java:168)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DataGenerationEngine.doExecuteQuery(DataGenerationEngine.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.execute(AbstractDataEngine.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ExecutionContext.executeQuery(ExecutionContext.java:1947)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.QueryItemExecutor.executeQuery(QueryItemExecutor.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.TableItemExecutor.execute(TableItemExecutor.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportItemEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportItemEmitterExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplicateItemExecutor.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportItemExecutor.execute(WrappedReportItemExecutor.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportItemExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportItemExecutor.java:34)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLBlockStackingLM.layoutNodes(HTMLBlockStackingLM.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLPageLM.layout(HTMLPageLM.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.layout.html.HTMLReportLayoutEngine.layout(HTMLReportLayoutEngine.java:100)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:269)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are missing some jar files for BIRT integration and that is why the class not found exception arises. Have a look at [the FAQ link for BIRT](http://wiki.eclipse.org/BIRT/FAQ/Deployment) to check which jar files might be necessary.

Comment: fine it had been working now but again it showing another error in console see update post